# How to launch silverlight with IE in Visual Studio while Google Chrome stays default for usual browsing

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight

I cannot debug silverlight with Google Chrome. I don't want to change default browser to IE for my normal internet browsing.

How to only ask to run IE when running a silverlight project in Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Visual Studio you can specify the browser to use when running a web project. Right click on the start webpage in your web project and click on the Browse With option.

In the dialog that appears click on Chrome and set it to default.

This will not change you default browser in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on ClientBin it is in your Projectweb.and change the default browser or remove the un wanted browser then click ok. Thats it.

or

ProjectWeb->Browse with->change the default browser->ok

Answer (score 0):

Or, just install the IETab extension for Chrome, then set it to automatically run the Silverlight page in IE mode.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd